# Eclipse project is not visible in eclipse which already exist in workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am using Eclipse for Android development. Today when I opened eclipse these is no projects visible in package explorer. Even though projects folders are present in directory. What can be reason for it? Is it missing some config file. How to make all projects in workspace visible again in explorer of eclipse.

Comment: it happens when eclipse is unexpectedly shutdown, you would have to import it, it might give you some errors

Answer (score 1):

Were the projects visible before?

Have you imported the projects to your workspace?  If no, import your projects into your workspace using following steps:

1. File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next
2. Select root directory: /path/to/project Projects → Select All
3. Uncheck Copy projects into workspace and Add project to working sets
4. Finish